# Jackson serialization: represent object by just a single member

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Consider a Java class with multiple members:

```
class MyClass{
    private OtherClass member;

    // more properties, getters...
    ...
}
```

Now, what can I do to represent `MyClass` by a serialized version of `member`? I've tried the `@JsonValue` annotation, but it works just for simple types (String, int).

Currently, I resolved that by using a custom serializer for `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClassSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyClass> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(
        MyClass myClass, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider
    ) throws IOException {
        serializerProvider.defaultSerializeValue(myClass.getMember(), jsonGenerator);
    }
}
```

, but it feels like that there must be a simpler solution.

Comment: My first idea is using [`JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) with fields you want to be ignored, if I haven't understood well please include some example.

Comment: @dariosicily That would work similarly, but it is not a good solution if you need just one member: everyone then needs to remember to mark new members with JsonIgnore too. Additionally, the JsonValue/Custom serializer solution has the advantage of a flattened hierarchy, the object with that single member is represented by that member in the serialized file.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification,  according to the documentation your initial idea of using  `JsonValue` with a getter should have worked with any serializable type.

Comment: The problem with `JsonValue` is that it serializes the annotated member as a value, while I need to serialize the member normally (i.e., apply standard serialization for the member).